# How to create multiple orders in one shopping cart rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've built a shopping cart and it works great (thanks to [this tutorial](https://richonrails.com/articles/building-a-shopping-cart-in-ruby-on-rails)).  Now I'm trying to modify it to my needs.  I would like an order to be created based on the seller_id attribute so that a shopper can see multiple orders from different sellers in their shopping cart similar to eBay or Etsy:

[image]

This is in my order_items_controller:

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.seller_id = @order_item.seller_id
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
  end
```

This is in my application_controller:

```
def current_order
   if !session[:order_id].nil?
      Order.find(session[:order_id])
    else
      Order.new
    end
```

I thought that changing the definition of current_order to:

```
def current_order
  Order.find_or_create_by(seller_id: :seller_id)
end
```

would solve things but it creates duplicate orders. I've tried several other variations and all produce errors.  Can someone help me out?  Even just on how to think about this differently?

Comment: Associate each order with a seller_id, and conditionally display each order on your cart's page

Comment: Can you associate a model to something that is not a model?  I guess I associate it w/ a user id and then define that user id as the seller id to associate the two.

Comment: Read this one: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html